Which chapter of the manga does Season 7 of My Hero Academia anime end in?
If I want to keep following My Hero Academia story in the manga, after the seventh season of the anime ended, which chapter of the manga the anime do I have to read?
Which chapter of the manga does Season 7 of My Hero Academia anime end in?

This website lists the correspondence of the manga/anime episodes. It says that the anime covers up to Volume 39, and the sequel is from Volume 40, Episode 399.
Note that the last volume has not appeared yet.
